# Why does stopwatch tick longer when it is running the first time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, stopwatch

I run this code inside a while loop for like 10000 times, I noticed timeSpent is around 4 except for the first time, which is ~500, why?

```
Stopwatch s;
long price;
count = 10000;
while (count!=0)
{
   s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

   price = classA.Method(..some inputs...);  //this method do some iterations to return back a long given some inputs

   s.Stop();
   timeSpent = s.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L * 1000L));
   s.Reset();
   /*write the price, timeSpent and inputs into a .txt file*/
   count--;
}
```

Comment: What are the /* Function calls */?   One of them might be initializing something.

Comment: Shouldn't you start the stopwatch *outside* the loop?

Comment: Even if it is initializing something, it will initialize again when it is being called again isn't it?

Comment: I would like to count the average of the time being used for function calls

Comment: You should try to isolate it by adding say a int counter and only call the functions if > 1.

Comment: I suspect the function calls you've omitted are being hit for the first time and you're seeing the cost of using a JIT language.

Comment: What was the purpose of that update? We still don't know what that method does.

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be clear now. Basically I want to see how long does the ClassA.Method() takes to return for different inputs

Comment: It is much easier to use Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds than doing the math yourself with Ticks

Comment: But I would like to have microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time a method is called, it is compiled from IL to native code. Any subsequent calls re-use the generated native code. So, in general, you would expect the first time you call a method to take the longest.

It's difficult to prove this is the cause, unfortunately, but that *might* explain it. I've seen this same thing happen many times when benchmarking / profiling: the first call takes the longest. I've usually worked around this by just discarding the first run.

Of course, the method you're calling could have side-effects, acquire resources and cache them, or just anything that only happens once and only on the first call. These are just some of the reasons I say it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Or one of the classes has a static constructor.